# Modifying entries of a matrix selectively

Tags: matlab

In my linear algebra class we have a small component of learning Matlab with the occasional assignment.

The question asked to modify an existing (not shown) $25 \times 25$ matrix with the following conditions:

1. if an entry in the matrix $B$ is $\geq 0$ then multiply by $4$
2. if an entry in the matrix $B$ is $<0$ then add $6$ to it

I created a function file in Matlab by doing the following:

```
function [A] = modify_matrix(B, n, m),
    A = zeros(n,m); 
    for i = 1:n, 
        for j = 1:m, 
            if B >= 0, 
                A = B*4; 
            else,
                A = B+6; 
                A(i,j) = B(i,j); 
            end 
        end 
    end
end
```

This simply reproduces the same matrix $B$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You said $B*4$, but all that does is return a value. You need to assign it, i.e. $A = B*4$.

Comment: Thanks, I changed that but it still is not modifying matrix B

Comment: Do you mean even if just one entry was positive we multiply whole the matrix by 4 or just do the case with that individual entry?

Comment: just the individual entry

Comment: i modified what I posted originally. I was able to produce a matrix that only added 4 when entries were <0 but for some reason it would not multiply by 4 when entry was >=0

Answer (score 0):

Using [Matlab vectorization tricks](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/programs/Matlab/tricks.html) you can do that in one line:

```
 A=B.*(B>0)*4+(B+6).*(B<0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what your if-else is missing in your code:

```
if B(i,j) >= 0, 
    A(i,j) = 4*B(i,j); 
else,
    A(i,j) = 6+B(i,j); 
end
```

Those `(i,j)` are what enables you to access/modify an entry.

However, as Dmitry pointed out, Matlab enables us to operate over matrices directly (I'm proposing my own variation of Dmitry's one-liner):

```
A = 4*B.*(aux = (B>=0)) +(B+6).*(1-aux)
```